# How to query data from SSAS Tabular in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssas-tabular

I am unable to find any useful resources on this. 
Basically, we are working on ASP.NET web API which needs to consume the SSAS Tabular Model.

I went through [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient), but it looks like its specific for Multidimensional models and not for the Tabular ones.

What is the cleanest way to query SSAS Tabular using C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adomdcommand can be used for Tabulars as well passing DAX query and connection to Tabular. Its possible to read from Tabulars.

Below link has an example to read from Tabular using OLEDB and ADOMD.
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/execute-dax-queries-through-ole-db-and-adomd-net/